# How do I integrate VoIP in my asp.net website?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5, voip

How can I integrate Voice over IP into my asp.net website so that user's can speak to each other through the site?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe using flash ? http://www.riapedia.com/2007/01/31/is_flash_about_to_dominate_voice_over_ip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without extra software (plugins) I don't believe you can at the moment with any mainstream browser (you probably would not want your computer microphone available to your browser as default for security reasons also, although plugins tend to get around this by asking for permission to access the microphone and camera).

Note that it is a non-trivial exercise to make this work reliably due to the need to work around NATS and firewalls - Skype and the new Google Voice chat feature for example dedicate a lot of their effort to achieving this reliably. If you decide to use a plugin it would be worth checking it handles this well (along with general voice quality). See the link below for some background: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Traversal_Utilities_for_NAT.